# Is there any "concatenable" video format I can use for sequential streaming?

Tags: encoding, streaming, file-formats

I'm writing a server and I have to play commercials on demand, so I'm trying to avoid re encoding video.

I assume that video containers have headers and meta data, so it would not be possible.

Is there a format (preferably compressed) that is proper to stream one video after the other without re encode or stopping the streaming? Concatenable in a binary sense, and still playable.

Comment: Welcome! If you haven't already, look at [HLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Live_Streaming) and [MPEG DASH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Adaptive_Streaming_over_HTTP) for widely adopted methods of solving your problem.

Comment: I really don't know much about video formats, but this seems exactlty what I'm looking for, allied with fragmentation might do the trick, tyvm.

Comment: For server applications and automated, scripted concatenation and encoding, I recommend you take a look at ffmpeg.

Comment: I did it! Can I post my solution here as an anwswer? (It has some c# code)